# How to force a user to take a suggested entry into a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, .net-4.0, combobox

I want a user to select a value from a ComboBox. Entries *have to be suggested* at user's text input.

Do I have to use events to enforce a `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` to contain a value from its own `DataSource`?

**Example:** Entries have to be suggested to the user... If I write "CO", the combo should suggest "CONGO" and "COLOMBIA", but only one of those values should be entered by the user. The user should not introduce "COfdfgdfg" or any random string.

Thanks!

Comment: Combobox.DropDownStyle (i believe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use combobox.autocompletemode to get the names liek Congo,congress when the user enter the text like "CO"

you can your  own datasource to comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource

```
 this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
this.comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(113, 192);
 this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 20);
```

Then populate the combox items source with objects like, that override the ToString method

```
public class POCLRO
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return Name;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**  You have to do validation on text entered by the user in combobox , if the user selects the drop down item suggested by auto completemode the validation returns true else it returns false ...

Do something like below ...

Create a KeyDown event handler for the combobox and check for an Enter key. Note that after the user hits enter the text in the combobox is selected (as in, selected as if you were doing a cut or copy operation) and focus remains in the combobox.

If enter was pressed call a validation function that will do whatever you feel necessary if the value entered is equal with name that was stored in database...

You can call this same function in a Leave event handler to prevent the user from leaving the combobox until a valid selection is made.

```
 private void ComboBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
 {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        ValidateSelection();
    }
 }

 private  bool validation()
 {
   // do validation here 
 }
private void ComboBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!ValidateSelection())
    {
        ComboBox.Focus();
    }
 }
```

Comment: I've made something like your example... but only with the Leave event... thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Set the combo box's style to ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

Comment: Entries have to be suggested to the user... If I write "CO", the combo should suggest "CONGO" and "COLOMBIA", but only one of this values should be entered by the user. The user should not introduce "COfdfgdfg" or any random string.

Comment: @JuanPabloContreras you have to use property of combobox like  combobox.autocompletemode property to get those suggestions..

Comment: @errorstacks yes, I know... what I meant is that I need the selected suggestion to be one previously contained in the DataSource