# How to code a generic ComboBox to force a user to select a suggested entry?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, architecture, combobox

This is an extension for: [How to force a user to take a suggested entry into a ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759887/how-to-force-a-user-to-take-a-suggested-entry-into-a-combobox)

How can a solution using events (like Leave and SelectedIndexChanged) be implemented in a generalized way? For example: I have implemented those methods for many comboboxes with a common behavior; the code is the same for Leave event on all Combos, so I think I can subclass or use a partial class but I do not know how to do it in an architecturally proper way or if I could use a new subclassed component in VSTS2010 GUI editor.

Try to think this as creating a customized combo that has to enforce the user to write a value already existing in its related `DataSource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom control that inherits from `ComboBox` (instead of inheriting from `UserControl`) and put all your logic in there.

Comment: Can the new control be used with VSTS2010 designer?

Comment: If VSTS2010 still supports UserControls (and I would assume that it does), then yes. I don't have it, so I don't know.