# TextBox Autocomplete Up and Down key Cant Select item in list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In C# Winforms, I have a textbox with AutoCompleteMode. When the user types some letters the suggestion list is shown Correctly. If an item in list is selected using (Keyboard)UP and Down key it could not Select an item. If i Select mean, it will get the first item in list..

Please Suggest..

Here My Code...

```
private void txt_Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader datareader = qu.GetValue("English_Short");
                AutoCompleteStringCollection local = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                if (datareader.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (datareader.Read())
                        local.Add(datareader["English_Short"].ToString());
                }
                txt_Name.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                txt_Name.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txt_Name.AutoCompleteCustomSource = local;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
```

Comment: May help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759887/how-to-force-a-user-to-take-a-suggested-entry-into-a-combobox?lq=1

Comment: Why put the building up your list at Text Changed event why not on form load?

Answer (score 1):

Why not put it in Form Load event instead of Text Changed:

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

      try
            {
                SqlDataReader datareader = qu.GetValue("English_Short");
                AutoCompleteStringCollection local = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                if (datareader.HasRows == true)
                {
                    while (datareader.Read())
                        local.Add(datareader["English_Short"].ToString());
                }
                txt_Name.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                txt_Name.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txt_Name.AutoCompleteCustomSource = local;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
              MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

  }
```